# PHP Xampp can not send mail

Tags: php, email, xampp, sendmail, ini

I have problem with mail() function in PHP. 
My ini files:
php.ini:

```
[mail function]
SMTP = smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port = 587
sendmail_from = myemail@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "C:\wamp\sendmail\sendmail.exe -t"
```

My C:/xampp/sendmail/sendmail.ini file:

```
[sendmail]
smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
smtp_ssl=auto
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=myemail@gmail.com
auth_password=mypass
force_sender=myemail@gmail.com
```

The code:

```
mail("xyz@gmail.com", "title", "message");
```

I get this error in localhost:

> Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()

Any idea what can I do?

Comment: Hi, 

You need to activate in GMAIL the less secure application to authorize the connection.

If you don't Google will block all connection tentative.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I still got this err.

Comment: I had to set `auth_password` in `sendmail.ini` to Google App Password. And also set 2 Step Verification in [http://myaccount.google.com/][1]. Thats all. Thanks for your attention.


  [1]: http://myaccount.google.com/